# How to speed up calabash-android query speed

Tags: android, calabash

```
How to speed up calabash-android query
```

query always take 2-3 seconds. For each query it takes around 2-3 seconds how to minimize it. I am using 0.4.6 version of calabash

for ex.

```
date       time        query
10/22/2013 2:32:15 PM: query("*").
10/22/2013 2:32:18 PM: [0]....

10/22/2013 2:32:36 PM: query("*").
10/22/2013 2:32:39 PM: [0]....

10/22/2013 2:33:17 PM: query("webview css:'input'").
10/22/2013 2:33:19 PM: [0]....

10/22/2013 2:34:35 PM: x=query("button id:'dashboard_button_01'").
10/22/2013 2:34:37 PM: [0]....

10/22/2013 2:35:21 PM: touch x.
10/22/2013 2:35:22 PM: {..}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your tests seem to be running slow, I am guessing it could be because you are testing in simulator. Which can be really slow.

Assuming that the emulator is making this slow for you, you can follow the guidelines here on how to speed up the emulator on intelhardware http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/speeding-up-the-android-emulator-on-intel-architecture

It gives a huge boost in performance of the emulator.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer. I hope it was of help and that you now how a fast emulator running.

Answer (score 0):

1) I have notice queries are quiker than perform action 
so avoid performAction if you can

2) if you have to mutiple queries to make on a view, make one query and then capture results into array and then analyse results using ruby code.
use this function `**wait_for_elements_exist(elements_arr, options={})**` if you want to wait for more than one element

Answer (score 0):

Try [GenyMotion](http://www.genymotion.com) emulator instead of default SDK one. It runs extremely faster, and query performs really fast as well.